# What's a noun to describe the state of blinking?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

To follow an existing pattern in my program, I need a noun to describe the state of (not) blinking or flashing.

> Default color
>
> Default brightness
>
> Default...?

'Solidity' almost works, but implies transparency or opacity.  What else can I use?

Comment: The best I can come up with is "flashing state" or "blinking state". Neither of which are particularly satisfactory, hence posting this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Is this state simply true/false, or would it include the speed of the blinking/flashing (with 0 or some other value to indicate no blinking)?

Comment: On the one hand I'd be tempted to use something like 'blinkiness', and on the other I'm tempted to say "NEVER MAKE THINGS BLINK" and then you won't need this word (or setting).

Comment: @Jim For the time being, it's simply true/false.  If that ever changes, it will use words rather than numbers.  For example, "solid," "fast blinking" and "slow blinking."

Comment: Default annoyingness?

Comment: @Hellion: +1 for "blinkiness" -- that's the first word that came to my mind. The second was "flashiness".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the word *animation*, as below.

> Default animation: Blinking / Off

Comment: I feel this is the next best answer after @Fraser's

Answer (score 10):

I don't like the answers "constancy" or "stable" they don't convey the essence of the domain you are looking for. Since you are using short phrases rather than fully grammatical sentences what is wrong with:

```
Default color       --- Red
Default brightness  --- 90%
Default blink       --- Off
```

You could also use:

```
Default blink rate  --- 0 for off, 5 for 5 blinks per secs.
```

It isn't really correct, but it conveys the meaning is spades. In computer user interfaces generally speaking the latter is much more important than the former.

Answer (score 1):

Default mode: on/blinking or off

Answer (score 1):

The closest match I can think of would be:

```
Default stable
```

or

```
Default stability
```

It's not a perfect match, though.

Answer (score 1):

Were it me (and I write enough device drivers that it may well be me one day), I'd go with "blink state".

That's only if there are more than two values though. For variables that are described by a boolean state (two possible values), it is typical computer idiom to use a name that is a question, like `is_blinking`, or a simple (falsifiable) statement like `blinking`.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is *constancy*.

Comment: Um, why the downvote? An explanation would be welcome; I wouldn't have suggested the word if I didn't think it might work.

Answer (score 0):

How about *blinkability*? I'm not sure how grammatically correct it is, but it make sense and is clear.